# Is there any drawback in using ECMAscripts "bracket notation" to access an object property?

Tags: javascript

I would like to use ECMAscripts "bracket notation" to use the key of an object as a name (which will be displayed in my menu, thus it can not be a short name without space like in propertyName).

In a word, I would like to write

```
object["Property name"]
```

instead of

```
object.propertyName
```

Is there any reason why I should not do that (except that the "bracket notation" is a bit longer)?

Comment: [Square bracket seems to slower (in microscopic terms)](http://jsperf.com/square-bracket-vs-dot), but other than that; there is no difference I can think of.

Comment: ECMAscript doesn't automatically convert between `["Property name"]` and `.PropertyName`. These are _different_ properties, and you cannot refer to `"Property name"` with dot notation.

Answer (score 0):

As you have stated, you can't use dot notation (`obj.property`), when there is space in variable name. So if your variable name does contain space character, than use `["bracket notation"]`